# How to populate PeoplePicker control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to use Javascript to populate a PeoplePicker control in Sharepoint 2013:

```
name="Engineer"
var ppDiv=$("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='"+name+"']");
console.log(ppDiv.html());
var ppEditor=ppDiv.find("[title='"+name+"']");
var spPP=SPClientPeoplePicker.SpClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv[0].id];
ppEditor.val("Abc, Xyz");
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

Two problems:  `ppDiv` is still undefined after the assignment statement, and `SPClientPeoplePicker` is not defined; according to [this article](https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/javascript-and-working-with-the-sharepoint-2013-people-picker/), it’s defined by `clientpeoplepicker.js`, which is a script that’s supposed to be loaded on every page that has a People Picker.

EDIT:

I changed the code to:

```
name="Engineer"
var ppDiv=$("div[title='"+name+"']");
console.log(ppDiv.html());
var ppEditor=ppDiv.find("[title='"+name+"']");
var spPPD=SPClientPeoplePicker.SpClientPeoplePickerDict;
console.log(spPPD[0]);
var spPP=spPPD[ppDiv[0].id];
ppEditor.val("Abc, Xyz");
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

Now ppDiv is defined (as shown by its HTML successfully appearing in the console log), but it's crashing on the line `var spPPD=SPClientPeoplePicker.SpClientPeoplePickerDict;` with this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined
```

Comment: Could it be the concatenation within the $() call? Try wrapping 

"[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='"+name+"']"

in parenthesis? It's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson, do you mean that this isn't enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I mean it's hard to tell what the problem is without more code, though I am sure I'd get an error copy-pasting the text provided.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson, right, you'd have to change the `name` value to the title of a control on your page, and change the value passed to `ppEditor.val()` to one of the user names that you have in your People Picker.  That should be enough to replicate it if you paste this into another script that you have running on your page.

Comment: Well, `SPClientPeoplePicker` **is** defined, when the page has loaded, but probably not when you run your code. All the javascript libraries are loaded on page load, but you might have to wait for it to be loaded. Just use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to wait for it to load, like this. `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
            //run your code here or call a function
        }, "clientpeoplepicker.js");`

Comment: Related: [How Can I Use the SharePoint People Picker Control in my Custom Web Part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/49332/65896)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it. With fieldName beeing the column title of the people picker and userAccountName the user login name/last part of the claim.

One thing to point out is that it has to be a client people picker. As far as i know, sharepoint uses server side people picker by default in custom forms so make sure its really a client people picker.

```
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {

var controlName = fieldName;

var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");

var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");

var spPeoplePicker =   SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];

peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);

spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

//disable the field

spPeoplePicker.SetEnabledState(false);

//hide the delete/remove use image from the people picker

$('.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').css('display','none');

}
```

Comment: "One thing to point out is that it has to be a client people picker." Thanks for mentioning that.  I dug a little deeper and found out that this was my issue.  No such creature on my page. :(

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I add a 500-700ms delay before calling the code, that I do not get this error:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
      SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("PickerFieldName", "emailAddress@company.com");
      }, 750);

    function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {
      var controlName = fieldName;
      var peoplePickerDiv = jQuery("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
      var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
      var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
      peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
      spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
    }
```

Comment: using hardcoded delays is considered a bad practice. best to react to an event.

Comment: Much better to use [ExecuteOrDelay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341724/how-to-populate-peoplepicker-control#comment56452993_34341724), because sooner or later your environment (server, network, browser, codebase, etc) will change, and the speed will change with it.